How I can compare two different CMC connected ports/PCBs for HDMI 2 connections via tests and oscilloscope?
I am trying to analyse and compare two different ports with different CMC for TMDS lines, but as in HDMI 2 compliance tests it is hard to see any eye test, I don't know how to compare. They seem super similar to me. As an electrical engineering student, my knowledge is still limited.

Well, what exactly are you supposed to compare? Signal edges? Filtering abilities? In case of the latter, you'd probably like to inject noise of a certain frequency into the signal, then see how well it filters noise of that frequency.
